What will be my internet speed for 10GB ethernet card on a PCI 2.0 x1 slot?
I have an Asus Motherboard  _PRIME_H310M-A_R2.0. The motherboard has a PCI Express 2.0 x 1 slots.
I have subscribed to a 5Gbps  bandwidth speed from my ISP.
I am going to buy a TP-Link 10GB PCIe Network Card (TX401) to maximize my new internet speed.
Does my old Asus motherboard able to support the new TP-Link 10GB PCIe Network Card ?

It will work, but you will be limited to 0.5 GB/sec instead of ~4.0 GB/sec.  In other words, it will be as fast as your current 10/100/1000 network card.
